# Angular Elements EventEmmitter : $event not showing emitted value

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I am stuck while working with Custom Angular Elements, Whenever i emit a value i.e `true` or `false`, it works fine while using `element` in same angular project, whenever i use the element in other project by creating its bundled `JS` file. It shows the `Inputs events` in the parent component.

This is my Angular Elements in Parent Component

```
<app-address [model]="address"  [isAddressValid]="isValid" 
(getValidity)="getValue($event)" placeholder="placeholder" label="label" isRequired="false" ></app-address>
```

In parent Component i am accessing value like

```
getValue(data) {
   console.log(data)
}
```

Instead of showing emitted data i.e `true` or `false` its showing me `inputs` event.

This is how i am importing file

```
import '../../../Elements/angular-address-element/elements/app-address-element'
```

**Child Component**

```
@Output() getValidity = new EventEmitter<any>();
this.getValidity.emit(true)
```

I am calling this `emit` on `change` event.

Comment: Show me the code how you emit the data in your child component

Comment: @TonyNgo please see updated question

Comment: @TonyNgo its showing me `$event` of input instead of  `true` or `false`

Comment: how come you're getting false if your emitting true

Comment: @Paul `true` or `false` are on the basis of conditions. It not showing true or false. Its showing event of input

Comment: small improvement: use boolean instead of any here: @Output() getValidity = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-ykz2nh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular elements dispatch outputs as custom events `document.createEvent('CustomEvent')` . That means you will always get a proper event object and never a primitive.

> Component outputs are dispatched as HTML Custom Events, with the name of the custom event matching the output name. For example, for a component with @Output() valueChanged = new EventEmitter(), the corresponding custom element will dispatch events with the name "valueChanged", and the emitted data will be stored on the event’s detail property. If you provide an alias, that value is used; for example, @Output('myClick') clicks = new EventEmitter(); results in dispatch events with the name "myClick".

So your code should be something like:
`<some-element (someEvent)="eventHandler($event.detail)> </some-element>"`

See:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-angular-elements-uses-custom-events-mechanism-to-transmit-components-outputs-outside-angular-7b469386f6e2

https://angular.io/guide/elements#mapping

Comment: Isn't there any better way than this? Better way like send only the $event.detail in the custom element itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the boolean value emitted from the app-address component you'll need to check event.target.value or in your case data.target.value :-)