# Better way to get the event data in Angular Elements Custom Events

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-events, angular-elements

In angular elements, as per the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/elements#mapping) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215011/angular-elements-eventemmitter-event-not-showing-emitted-value) says emits a custom event whenever we emit a value using @output event emitter. But it's actually cumbersome to handle in the real usage side. Is there any other way to get **the real value emitted** other than calling $event.detail?

FYI:

if *The published value = 'abc*,

Then the event is like

```
CustomEvent {isTrusted: false, detail: "abc", type: "ngModelChange", ... }
```

Comment: u can use service without emitters if u want

Comment: You find it cumbersome to get the value with `$event.detail`? What would you consider not cumbersome?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question, if you use in your component, this.myOutput.emit("abc"), $event get the value "abc"

Comment: @ConnorsFan haha problem is with my question. Actually it's not cumbersome to use like $event.detail when in the ts file or anywhere. But here i am using this as the [(ngMode)]="bindingVariable" style. You got the point why i'm telling this cumbersome now? :D. Coz when we have a bind like that, it's almost impossible to get the actual value we passed (What we get is the whole custom event)

Comment: @Eliseo no actually. When i'm using the outputed value. The value coming up is something like the event that i have posted (CustomEvent {isTrusted: false, detail: "abc", type: "ngModelChange", ... })

Comment: @ConnorsFan P.S. :- I'm manually implementing the ngModel and ngModelChange thing because when in custom elements (angular elements) it don't work