# How to pass data from Angular Component to plain html page

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component

I am using Angular web components in a static html page. I am able to inject data into Angular component. But when I try to retrieve data from Angular component to the HTML page, it is not working. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

The code is as below:

**component ts code**

```
  @Output() myOutput:EventEmitter<string>= new EventEmitter();

  outputMessage:string="I am child component."
  
  sendValues() {
    this.myOutput.emit(this.outputMessage);
  }
```

**component html code**

```
<button (click)="sendValues"> Send Data </button>
```

**JS code in static html**

```
   var commCompTag = document.getElementsByTagName('comm-comp');
   if(commCompTag.length > 0){
      console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
      commCompTag[0].addEventListener('myoutput', (event) => {
         var evtDetails = event;
         console.log('evtDetails >>> ', evtDetails);
         console.log(event.detail);
      });
      // commCompTag[0].addEventListener('myoutput', function(event) {
      //   var evtDetails1 = event;

      //   console.log('evtDetails1 >>> ', evtDetails1);
      //   console.log(event.originalEvent.detail);
      // });
   }
```

I have tried the above solution by referring to [Angular Elements EventEmmitter : $event not showing emitted value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215011/angular-elements-eventemmitter-event-not-showing-emitted-value) but it didn't help me out. So it will be great if someone can give me some pointers to resolve this issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vnrj8a

Comment: Put something for the name of the output, i.e., `@Output("myOutput") ...`, or use the string `'myOutput'` as the name of the event rather than the all lower case value. Event names, as far as I know, should not be case-sensitive, but in the brave new world of web components, I'm not sure :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the index.html is technically not part of the bootstrapped angular app, you may need to resort to non Angular-specific solutions.

One approach/POC may be to do the following.

Get a reference to `my-app` element via constructor

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}
```

construct and dispatch an event on the `nativeElement`

```
sendValues() {
    console.log('sending values');
    this.myOutput.emit(this.outputMessage);
    const event = new CustomEvent('my-app-data', {
      detail: {
        value: {
          message: this.outputMessage
        }
      }
    });
    this.elRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

Register to listen for that event in `index.html`

```
jsonCommCompTag[0].addEventListener('my-app-data', function(event) {
      var evtDetails1 = event;

      console.log('evtDetails1 >>> ', evtDetails1.detail.value.message);
    });
```

don't forget invocation in your button click event handler in `app.component.html`

```
(click)="sendValues()"
```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zbj7ru?file=src/index.html